Issue with forced linebreaks in the wrapstuff package
The wrapstuff package is a nice alternative to the wrapfig and wrapfig2 packages since it offers the ability to wrap text around figures which are center-aligned. An issue with it seems to be that its environment (\begin{wrapstuff}[]) can't handle forced linebreaks, however (I've tried \\ and \newline). When using the wrapfig2 package, this is no problem:

But when I switch to the wrapstuff environment, this happens:

As you can see, it only shows the text written after the linebreak in the 2nd example with wrapstuff. It works completely fine if you remove the linebreak. The documentation isn't of much help solving this issue, unfortunately. Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz, wrapstuff, wrapfig2, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\noindent The \verb|wrapstuff| package seems to fix the limitation of \verb|wrapfig, wrapfig2| as its only environment, \verb|wrapstuff|, can handle left-, right- and \textbf{center-aligned} figures! Let's demonstrate below:

\begin{wrapstuff}[c]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {fill opacity = 0.25, draw opacity = 1, text opacity=1, font=\sffamily},
    shader/.style ={top color = #1!20, bottom color = #1, middle color = #1!50},
    block/.style={draw=red, line width=0.4mm, shader = blue, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, text width=5cm, align=center, inner sep=5pt},
    arrow/.style = {red,-{Stealth[blue]}, line width=0.4mm, line cap=round, shorten >= 3pt, text = blue}
]
     \node[block] (calign) {Is it possible to wrap text around a center-aligned figure?};   
     \node[block, below left = of calign, xshift=3cm] (no) {No, because how should the text read? Like row or column?};
     \node[block, below right = of calign, xshift=-3cm] (yes) {Yes, make an option to read the text both ways!};
     \draw[arrow] (calign.south west) -- node[rotate=45, above] {Explanation} (no.120);
     \draw[arrow] (calign.south east) -- node[rotate=-45, above] {Explanation} (yes.60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapstuff} \noindent
What would happen if I just write some text here? What about more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more  and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more? \\ The moment I make a forced linebreak, however, will all of the text prior to it disappear?

\end{document}


I have no solution, but on GitHub an issue was raised: https://github.com/qinglee/wrapstuff/issues/16

You shouldn't use \\ in normal text --- if you need to end a paragraph, use \par, or leave a blank line which is the same:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz, wrapstuff, wrapfig2, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\noindent The \verb|wrapstuff| package seems to fix the limitation of \verb|wrapfig, wrapfig2| as its only environment, \verb|wrapstuff|, can handle left-, right- and \textbf{center-aligned} figures! Let's demonstrate below:

\begin{wrapstuff}[c]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {fill opacity = 0.25, draw opacity = 1, text opacity=1, font=\sffamily},
    shader/.style ={top color = #1!20, bottom color = #1, middle color = #1!50},
    block/.style={draw=red, line width=0.4mm, shader = blue, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, text width=5cm, align=center, inner sep=5pt},
    arrow/.style = {red,-{Stealth[blue]}, line width=0.4mm, line cap=round, shorten >= 3pt, text = blue}
]
     \node[block] (calign) {Is it possible to wrap text around a center-aligned figure?};
     \node[block, below left = of calign, xshift=3cm] (no) {No, because how should the text read? Like row or column?};
     \node[block, below right = of calign, xshift=-3cm] (yes) {Yes, make an option to read the text both ways!};
     \draw[arrow] (calign.south west) -- node[rotate=45, above] {Explanation} (no.120);
     \draw[arrow] (calign.south east) -- node[rotate=-45, above] {Explanation} (yes.60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapstuff} \noindent
What would happen if I just write some text here? What about more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more  and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more?

The moment I make a forced linebreak, however, will all of the text prior to it disappear?

\end{document}



If we go with the paragraph break solution which you've provided, is it correctly understood that you then need to use \vspace{} in order to adjust how far from the first paragraph the second one starts? What if you only want one additional line spacing below?

@Atex paragraph spacing should be a document setting, not a space you added each time (see parskip package for example)

Yes, and that's why it'd be nice to know what the correct way of having an additional line space between paragraphs. I typically like to use \setstretch{1.5} provided by the setspace package which ensures readable paragraphs in a document. I do not want the same spacing between lineshifts within a paragraph and between 2 paragraphs, however. Trying to deduce it, I've figured that <blank line> \noindent\\ <new paragaph> works so far, but I don't know if there's an optimal way of doing it, however.

Atex not sure to understand. setstrech is for interline space, or am I wrong? To separate paragraph visually you normally either use an indent at the paragraph start (Anglo-Saxon way, I think) or remove the indent and add a vertical space, like \parindent 0pt\parskip 0.5\baselineskip, or, better, use the parskip package as suggested by @DavidCarlisle

I wouldn't call setstretch of 1.5 readable, more white rivers of white space between lines to allow reviewers to write comments @Atex please don't ever use \noindent\\  You should almost never have \noindent or \\  in a document and absolutely  never use \\  after \noindent

Oh wow, it seems like there are many small "unwritten rules" for LaTeX which I'm unaware of. Do you guys know any good resources to get acquainted with these? And I must admit that I'm not a fan of indicating a new paragraph with an indented new line (hence why I've used the easy "quickfixes" as workarounds in the past such as \\), but I'll try the correct approach for starting a new paragraph with additional vertical space as you guys have suggested. I just wonder how many other small details /"unwritten rules" I don't know about for other instances?

@Atex no you should avoid all such markup, always just mark a new paragraph by a blank line, whether new paragraphs are typeset with a horizontal indent or with a vertical space is a document level design choice which should be set by the class or a package such as parskip, not something you mark individually on each paragraph.  \noindent\\  does not add vertical space it adds a white line of text that will not be dropped at a page break and will just make horrible output.

@Atex it's not an unwritten rule, is the basic philosophy for LaTeX: avoid non-semantic markup as much as you can. You say, "This is the title of a subsection", but leave the visual formatting (including numbering, indexing, etc.)  to the document class/specific document setup. The same at all levels, including the paragraph termination.

Oh wow, I learned so much more from this exchange than I expected! This really taught me that no matter how simple or insignificant a fix for a small issue can seem, it's worth it to learn the correct syntax, because the definitions can be so vastly different, even though the visual output may look the same. This has really motivated me to understand the definition/purpose behind the commands instead of just checking whether the visual output is as I desire. I shall use the parskip package from now on and be wary of every command I use in the future!

Rmano has shown how to have a paragraph break, if you really want it all in the same paragraph, it seems like you need to help a bit to keep it all in one line on its measuring pass

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz, wrapstuff, wrapfig2, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\noindent The \verb|wrapstuff| package seems to fix the limitation of \verb|wrapfig, wrapfig2| as its only environment, \verb|wrapstuff|, can handle left-, right- and \textbf{center-aligned} figures! Let's demonstrate below:

\begin{wrapstuff}[c]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {fill opacity = 0.25, draw opacity = 1, text opacity=1, font=\sffamily},
    shader/.style ={top color = #1!20, bottom color = #1, middle color = #1!50},
    block/.style={draw=red, line width=0.4mm, shader = blue, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, text width=5cm, align=center, inner sep=5pt},
    arrow/.style = {red,-{Stealth[blue]}, line width=0.4mm, line cap=round, shorten >= 3pt, text = blue}
]
     \node[block] (calign) {Is it possible to wrap text around a center-aligned figure?};   
     \node[block, below left = of calign, xshift=3cm] (no) {No, because how should the text read? Like row or column?};
     \node[block, below right = of calign, xshift=-3cm] (yes) {Yes, make an option to read the text both ways!};
     \draw[arrow] (calign.south west) -- node[rotate=45, above] {Explanation} (no.120);
     \draw[arrow] (calign.south east) -- node[rotate=-45, above] {Explanation} (yes.60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapstuff} \noindent
What would happen if I just write some text here? What about more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more  and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more?\hspace{\textwidth minus \textwidth}\penalty-50The moment I make a forced linebreak, however, will all of the text prior to it disappear?

\end{document}


Even though your solution is supposed to be for technically keeping it in the same paragraph, it seems like it has the desired effect for starting a new paragraph when leaving a blank space (the text doesn't just start on the line below, but on the 1 after it). Would it be wrong to use this approach for such a purpose? Or could it be modified to accomodate for this?

As I say it is not a new paragraph it is a single paragraph with a large interword space at one place then a normal automatic line break. It may look like a new paragraph but it isn't @Atex
